# Command Block Help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I want to be able to activate a redstone signal using a command block, but from way across the map. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `/setblock`. For example:

[image]

The left command block is whatever you want to put in it. For my example, I used

```
testfor @a
```

(This command tests if anybody is online...pretty simple).

The right command block is

```
setblock x y z redstone_block
```

Replace x,y, and z with whatever the coordinates are next to your redstone dust. So, I put a torch next to the left command block. It gets powered, makes a signal, powers the `setblock` command block, that command blocks sets a redstone block next to the redstone dust, and viola.
[image]

Comment: /setblock ~ ~ ~4

Comment: @Alex Yes, that was (close) to my command. However, I put `x y z` for the OP to put in their coords, and not confuse them.